# Restoring MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, software

My MacBook Pro froze.  I turned it off manually.  It won't come back on.  It is 1 year old.  I can't restart in Safe Mode.  I can restart using Command-R and get to Disk Utility but I don't know what to do next.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

If you get to the cmd-r screen there you should have the restore option.

Since your system froze, probably the best is to use restore the os x.

Your system has the Internet restore option.

In order to reinstall OS X, you need to be connected to the Internet over an Ethernet or Wi-Fi network. The Wi-Fi menu is in the upper-right corner of the screen. Click the icon to select from available Wi-Fi networks. Choose your preferred network name and, if needed, enter a username and/or password.

Now to the bad news: you probably had a disk error. It is big enough to also screw up your osx boot sector. Try holding the option key to see if it comes with the boot option. Since you do have access to the disk utility use it to try to repair your disk.

Now to the good news: Since your computer is probably still under warranty if above fails bring it in for repair.